# Problem with uploading file with livewire component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I create a component to create a post, my form has an input file with wire:model="post.post_image" , when I choose an image, I create a function to print the image data but it still gives me null.

```
use WithFileUploads;
public $post;

protected $rules = [
    'post.post_image' => 'sometimes|image|max:5000',
    ];

public function mount ()
{
    $this->post = new Post;
}
public function uploadPostImage(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->file('post.post_image'));
}
public function render ()
{
    return view('livewire.post.create');
}

html code :

<div class="sm:col-span-6"> <input type="file" accept="image/*" wire:model="post.post_image" name="post.post_image" wire:change="uploadPostImage"> </div>
```

when i upload image it give me null and in console give me this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKhZN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you see [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads) in the model of implementation for file upload, it is useless to count on the Request while using Livewire.
Check the model of implementation in the documentation, it is pretty easy.

Comment: I check the documentation so many time , but it still give me erro!

Comment: Your implementation you posted here, has nothing to do with the documentation on how to upload a file. Please check it again.